# Separation of geometric sequence do not have equal sum.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Suppose we remove some terms (taking at least 1 item and leaving at least 2 items) from the geometric sequence,
>   $$1, k, k^2, \cdots, k^{n}$$ 
>   (with $k>2$) and separate the remaining terms into two groups. Prove these two group's sum can never be the same.

I'm not even sure how to start on this since you can't find a closed form for a sum of group. The entire sum is 
$$\frac{1(1-k^{n+1})}{1-k}$$
So the we prove that $$\frac{\frac{1(1-k^{n+1})}{1-k}-(k^p+\cdots)}{2}$$
cannot be attained by the remaining terms.

Comment: This is a really interesting problem! (+1) Consider, however, not using the term 'group' as that might lead to confusion with an actual algebraic group.

Comment: Hint: $k^m > \frac{k^m-1}{k-1}$ for $k > 2$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider a splitting

$$A = k^{a_1} + \dots +k^{a_s},\quad B = k^{b_1} + \dots +k^{b_r},$$
where $0 \leq a_1 < \dots < a_s \leq n$ and the same holds for the $b_i$s. Without loss of generality suppose $b_r > a_s,$ so

$$A \leq 1 + k + k^2 + \dots + k^{a_s} = \frac{1-k^{a_s+1}}{1-k} < k^{a_s+1} \leq k^{b_r} \leq B,$$

so we get $A < B$.

Comment: FYI, what I've done a few times in the past, where I've given an answer which basically comes from question comment(s) and I provide little, if any, extra work, so I don't feel I should get any reputation gain, is to make the answer a community wiki. You can also do this later. Regardless, though, note that whenever you do it, you can't normally undo it later. If you wish to do this, you can edit your post and, at least in normal desktop mode, between the edit control with your text and the edit preview, on the right side, there's a "community wiki" checkbox you can check.